# jQuery Packery plugin not setting height properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, packery

I'm using the Packery plugin to give my image gallery a more interesting layout on a website I'm building.

Every now and then, I visit the page and some of the images are overlapping each other like so:

[image: Packery overlap]

But then when I refresh the page, it displays it properly:
[image: Packery]

I tried specifying a height on the container element but to no avail.

Here is the code I'm using:

CSS:

```
.packery-grid {
    min-height: 500px;
}

.packery-grid-03 {
    width: 20%;
}

.packery-grid-06 {
    width: 40%;
}

.packery-grid figure {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // visuals
    $('.packery-grid').packery({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.packery-grid-item',
        gutter: 0
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">

            <div class="packery-grid">

                <div class="packery-grid-item packery-grid-03">
                    <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-visual">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/255-198x127.jpg" alt="Six" />
                    </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>  

                <div class="packery-grid-item packery-grid-03">
                    <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-visual">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/319-198x127.jpg" alt="Five" />
                    </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="packery-grid-item packery-grid-03">
                    <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-visual">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/IMG_8204-198x127.jpg" alt="Four" />
                    </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="packery-grid-item packery-grid-06">
                    <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-visual">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/157-426x284.jpg" alt="Three" />
                    </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="packery-grid-item packery-grid-06">
                    <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-visual">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/IMG_4445-426x284.jpg" alt="Two" />
                    </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

                <div class="packery-grid-item packery-grid-03">
                    <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-visual">
                    <img src="http://somesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Iceland-198x127.jpg" alt="One" />
                    </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the solution on their support page

> Unloaded images can throw off Packery layouts and cause item elements
>   to overlap. imagesLoaded resolves this issue.

And so I've modified my code like so:

```
// visuals
var $grid = $('.packery-grid').packery({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.packery-grid-item',
    gutter: 0
});

    // layout Packery after each image loads
    // to prevent overlapping images
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
        $grid.packery();
    });
```